# Error in TRESTClient file download: No mapping for unicode character exists in target multi-byte code page

Tags: rest, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I want to download files with the `TRESTClient` library. However on some files I get the following error on the line of `RESTRequest1.Execute`:

> Project dllhst3g.exe raised exception class ERESTException with message 'REST request failed: Keine Zuordnung für Unicode-Zeichen in der Multibyte-Zielcodeseite vorhanden'.

English:

> No mapping for unicode character exists in target multi-byte code page

According to Fiddler, the request is sent and gets a response, which is a perfectly readable text file(`Content-Type`: `text/plain`). This looks like an encoding issue during the creation of the TRESTResponse object. The `Content-Disposition` response header is UTF-8 encoded, maybe that's the reason?:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=utf-8''my%20%28filename%29.TXT`

My code looks like this:

```
var
  RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
  RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;

RESTClient1 := TRESTClient.Create(myUrl);
RESTRequest1 := TRESTRequest.Create(RESTClient1);
RESTRequest1.AddAuthParameter('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + mySessionId, pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
RESTRequest1.AddParameter('Accept', 'application/octet-stream', pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
RESTRequest1.Execute;

if RESTRequest1.Response.StatusCode <> 200 then
begin
  // raise Exception
end;

result := RESTRequest1.Response.RawBytes;
```

How can I make sure that the response uses the correct encoding?

Comment: 'The Accept request HTTP header indicates which content types, expressed as MIME types, the client is able to understand.'

Comment: Which D11 Update level is installed?

Comment: `Content-Disposition` is not how the server should be reporting UTF-8 , it should be reported as a `charset` attribute on the `Content-Type` instead. That said, is the error actually in the call to `TRESTRequest.Execute()`, or is it actually when you access the `TRESTResponse` afterwards? What does the rest of your code look like that is using `TRESTResponse`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I suspect it happens when accessing `TRESTResponse`. I had the exact same issue the other day. However mine only happened after trying to assign the response json value to a label (FMX). When assigning it to a variable it does not throw the exception.

URL: `https://umod.org/plugins/no-give-notices.json` It gives me the same error when on the title and description json properties.

Comment: @RemyLebeau @Adriaan The error is in the call of `TRESTRequest.Execute()`. I added the `Content-Disposition` header and the following code to my question above.

Comment: I don't know if this is your Problem as well. In the Past I had some similar Problems and found out, that the Problem was in the "REST.HTTPClient.pas" in "procedure TRESTHTTP.RaiseProtocolException(const AResponse: IHTTPResponse);" try changing the raise statment into:
raise EHTTPProtocolException.Create(AResponse.StatusCode, AResponse.ContentAsString(TEncoding.ANSI),
    LMessage);

Comment: @JonasK did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn´t find a solution with the `TRESTClient` library, I´ll use Indy for now as a workaround:

```
using
  IdHTTP, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdGlobal;

var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;

lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
try
  lHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(lHTTP);
  lHTTP.IOHandler.MaxLineAction := maException;
  (lHTTP.IOHandler as TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL).SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;

  result := TStringStream.Create;
  lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + mySessionId);
  lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Accept', 'application/octet-stream');

  try
    lHTTP.Get(myUrl, result);
  except on e: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    raise Exception.Create(e.Message + ': ' + e.ErrorMessage);
  end;
finally
  lHTTP.Free;
end;
```